# How do I make the text bigger when a list also has an href?

Tags: html, html-lists

My current issue is that my list at the top of my website is a little too small. I am trying to make the text the size of .

I would so something like this

```
<li style="color:black;font-size:30px">Example </li>
```

But my list is an href and this will not work.

```
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">How Does it Work?</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">FAQ</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Discord Server</a></li>
        </ul>
</div>
```

So im unsure on what to do, any help would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a CSS file whenever possible. You could also use a style tag. But the following in your html file.

```
<style>
ul li,
ul li a {
    color:black;
    font-size:30px;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to select that a tag

Use this in css:

```
ul li > a {
    font-size: 30px;
}
```

this means it will select every a element which is a child of li.

Answer (score 1):

Try `<style>li a {color:black;font-size:30px;}</style>`.
This targets all `<a>` elements that are inside a `<li>` and applies the styles on them.

Answer (score 0):

This will style all the anchor tags inside an unordered list:

`ul a{font-size:30px;}`